# Timezone and DST problems on the latest 2014 Samsung Smart TV firmware

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, samsung-smart-tv

I have 2 Samsung Smart TVs with the following model and firmware (from TV Menu->Support->Contact Samsung screen)

1. 2013:

   - Model Code: UN32F5500
   - Software Vesrion: T-MST12AKUC-1121.3
2. 2014:

   - Model Code: UN40H6350
   - Software Vesrion: T-MST14AKUC-1115.3

The first problem (reproduced on both TVs, 2013 & 2014) is the timezone is detection is wrong. The following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/../webapi/1.0/deviceapis.js'></script>
// ...
var timezone = deviceapis.tv.info.getTimeZone();
window.alert('Timezone=' + timezone.timezone + ', dst=' + timezone.dst);
```

outputs the following:

```
Timezone=2, dst=0
```

This is `PL_TV_TIMEZONE_EASTERN` whereas I'm in the PST timezone, i.e. the following output is expected (`5` is `PL_TV_TIMEZONE_PACIFIC`, and daylight savings time is active now):

```
Timezone=5, dst=1
```

The most weird thing is that I'm not able to change the TV's timezone and DST setting. If I go to the TV's Menu->System->Time->Clock, then the 'DST' and 'Time Zone' settings are disabled (grayed out) even if the 'Clock Mode' setting is set to 'Manual'.

The second problem is specific for the 2014 TV, it's not reproduced on the 2013 TV. The `Date`'s `getUTCHours()` method returns wrong result not taking into account Daylight Saving Time Shift. That is, the following code:

```
var now = new Date();
window.alert('now: ' + now + '; getUTCHours()=' + now.getUTCHours());
```

produces the following output:

```
now: Fri Aug 08 2014 18:12:52 GMT-0800 (GMT), getUTCHours()=2
```

whereas the following is expected (as on my 2013 TV):

```
now: Fri Aug 08 2014 18:12:52 GMT-0700 (PDT); getUTCHours()=1
```

The current time (`Fri Aug 08 2014 18:12:52`) is correct but the DST offset is not taken into account in the returned GMT time's hour. Also, timezone code in the parenthesis is wrong (GMT instead of PDT or rather, taking into account timezone error described above, EDT or EST).
I observed this problem just recently, I think it appeared after I made Software Update for the 2014 TV. I'd rather think this is a bug introduced in the latest version of the firmware.
I tried to use `TV` plugin's (`clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-TV`) `GetDST()`, `GetTimeZone()`, `GetTimeZone_Offset()` functions, but all of them return incorrect results.

I'd very appreciate any help provided.

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever *Date.prototype.toString* returns is completely implementation dependent, so you should ignore that and use the *get\** methods. It seems that you can only select the time zone (which seems to be region based, not actually time zone based) if you set the clock to auto.

Comment: @RobG, thank you for reply! I actually use `get*` methods (in the sample code from the question I use `getUTCHours()`), I (indirectly) use the `toString()` method just for illustration purposes. The problem is those `getUTC*` methods I'm using also return incorrect results. I can't use timezone provided by the system as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just contacted Samsung support, and they suggested that the Input had to be set to "TV" before entering setup to have access to the Timezone and the other parameters.

Comment: Thank you, Rick! Unfortunately the project is over and I'm not able to verify if this solution works for me. But nevertheless I mark your answer as accepted as definitely it's most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it absolutely sounds like a firmware problem to me.  I'd consider taking it up with [their technical support](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Support).  (Good luck.)

If time zone issues are important for your app and you're looking for a workaround, consider providing your own time zone data with your application.  Assuming you can run any JavaScript you want, you should be able to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on.

Comment: There is no magic in *moment.js*. If the built–in Date methods are reporting the wrong time zone offset, it can't fix them.

Comment: Not by itself, but with moment-timezone providing the timezone data it can.  Of course, it will require manually mapping the [proprietary time zone code](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00001/tv.info_158.html#Constants) from this device to an appropriate IANA identifier (such as `TIMEZONE_USA_PACIFIC` == `America/Los_Angeles`).

Comment: The device isn't reporting the timezone (PDT), just the offset (GMT-0800) and not adjusting for daylight saving. So a timezone sniffer will get it wrong and guess at a region that is UTC-0800 and doesn't observe daylight saving—wherever that might be, maybe Pitcairn Standard Time (PST)?.

Comment: I was working off the assumption that this device's own API `deviceapis.tv.info.getTimeZone().timezone` mentioned [here](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00001/tv.info_158.html#getTimeZone) would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for feedback! Unfortunately, the `deviceapis.tv.info.getTimeZone().timezone` returns wrong time zone (please see log output listed in my question), so I can't rely on it.

Comment: Well, you could try [jsTimeZoneDetect, ](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/), but I'm not sure how accurate it will be on this device and under the conditions you described.  It sounds like only a firmware update would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung supplied me with a link for my model that had me reset the Country Code to Virgin Islands, US, then back to US.

This resets the apps & Timezone/date.

This fixed the issue for me.

If you have different models, you might want to contact Samsung Chat to get a link for yours.

How to reset Country Code (Timezone) on my model per Samsung
http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=428459&modelname=UN55F6300AF&modelcode=UN55F6300AFXZA